# Removing Space Under HTML Figure Tag with Image

Tags: html, css, image, figure

I'm trying to understand why removing space below HTML figure tag requires a hack.

In Chrome, removing the default "vertical-align: baseline" works, but when you add that in the CSS, it doesn't. The only hack I was able to come up with to make it work is to add a wrapper div around the image and then set "line-height: 0".

```
<figure style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="line-height: 0;">
        <img src="http://wellnesscounselingmilwaukee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1.jpg">
    </div>
</figure>
```

Any idea? It makes no sense at all whatsoever.

Here's the screenshot from JSFiddle for those who somehow can't replicate. I tested this on latest version of Chrome and Safari. This is the exact same issue with table and people normally use a different hack for that. The screenshot doesn't show the part that I unchecked "line-height: 0;" btw in case you were wondering. If you copy and paste the code into JSFiddle, you have to uncheck it to see the issue.

[image]

Here's the link to the one you don't have to modify.

https://jsfiddle.net/415s3amz/1/

---

Update:

If you have an option to set the image to display: block; It will also solve the issue. If not, use line-height: 0; What this seems to have proven based on the tests is that this has to do with default behavior of the image element. However, it still makes no sense that unchecking vertical-align: baseline works, but adding the same CSS doesn't work.

Comment: Why you don't do a `margin: 0;` on the `figure` element?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. All I see when I post your code is https://jsfiddle.net/xs7jxL60/

Comment: I added a random image so now you can paste on JSFiddle. "margin: 0;" doesn't work.

Comment: Just to prove the point, I will also add margin: 0 and remove figcaption. Do an inspect element in JSFiddle and you will see space at the bottom of figure below the image.

Comment: `margin:0` seems to work... What do you mean by "space below html figure tag?"

Comment: Are you referring to the <figurecaption>?

Comment: Ok. I will add the screenshot so you can see the extra pixels.

Comment: It's nothing to do with <figcaption>. I removed it for simplicity. Just take a look at the screenshot. The most obvious way to see this is to actually add another element and you will see the annoying gap that you can't get rid of without this hack. It seems like no one ever paid attention to it including whoever voted this question down.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the blue highlighting. Look at the element dimensions. the figure is exactly the same size as the div it is holding.

Comment: It's not a misunderstanding. This might sound arrogant, but I have done this for 17 years + spent the past hour trying to find way around it. This is an actual issue and I would love to know why it's happening. I will add another element below it to prove the point in the sample and you will see what the issue is about.

Comment: What happens when you put an element below it? What exactly is the problem? What are you not able to do? Seems to be working exactly as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the vertical alignment of the image from baseline (the default) to top:

```
img {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/415s3amz/2/)**
 Inline elements leave space for text descenders (characters that go below the line line g, y, j) so you need to change the vertical alignment if you want to get rid of that gap.

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion after trying out a few way. This is all to do with behavior of display: inline-block. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting! So the problem came from the `img` tag (inline-block), not the `figure` tag.

Answer (score 2):

`margin:0` should remove the default margins. The `<figure>` tag is taking the size of the `div` within it which is a block level element and therefore expands full width when empty. See snippet... Both the `figure` and `div` have the same dimensions (width of container, height 150)

```html
<figure style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="line-height: 0;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</figure>
```

Additional snippet showing no space below the `figure`

```html
<figure style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="line-height: 0;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</figure>
<figure style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="line-height: 0;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was very clear. This has nothing to do with the width. It's the space below that is an issue.

Comment: Of course you won't. You have my hack in there. Remove "line-height: 0" and you will see the issue.

Comment: @juminoz I see... you should remove the line-height from your question example. Show the problem you are experiencing not the fix. Or show both to contrast.

Answer (score 0):

This quote from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) might help clarify things a bit (I bolded the important part):

> The HTML  element represents self-contained content,
>   frequently with a caption (), and is typically referenced
>   as a single unit. While it is related to the main flow, **its position
>   is independent of the main flow**. Usually this is an image, an
>   illustration, a diagram, a code snippet, or a schema that is
>   referenced in the main text, but that can be moved to another page or
>   to an appendix without affecting the main flow.

Usually when items are taken out of the normal flow of layout they behave differently (like using `position: absolute` etc), which is why I think that using `margin: 0;` doesn't work (at least not for all browsers). Removing the margin seems to work in Firefox.

When I view the code in Chrome I see this for its CSS:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

So setting those values to `0` would remove the margin spacing for Chrome.

In [IE it seems there is only partial support](http://caniuse.com/#search=figure) at least for now:

> Partial support refers to missing the default styling, as technically
>   the **elements are considered "unknown"**. This is easily taken care of by
>   manually setting the default display value for each tag.

Hopefully this helps. [You can see my js.fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xs7jxL60/5/).